# Why am I getting a filled shape using pen tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I have gone through many of tutorial and none explains this effect I am getting here:

[image]

I select Pen tool > Change to "Path" and draw two anchor points and a get a shape like above.

How can I draw a curve without it filling it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two things at work:

First you have the tool set to shape, and then you have the fill set to black. You can leave it on Shape but change the fill to empty. Or you can change it from Shape to Path.

[image]

**Update**

You at some point made it a Shape. So you've got two options. Either set the Fill to Empty. Or in that path panel click Create New Path on the bottom. Now go to the Shape Path and using the Path Selection Tool (Black Arrow) select your shaped path and do copy. Then switch to the newly created empty path and click paste. Then delete the shape one.

Comment: I have it set to Path already but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user121321 did you start with it on path or did you change it to path? Changing it to path won't fix it.

Comment: Ryan: I am starting with path (I also mentioned in question).

Comment: @user121321 then I think you switched to Path but at some point hit Shape next to it. Check your Paths panel and see if it says Work Path or Shape Path. I suspect it says Shape Path.

Comment: I checked the panel on right with "Layers, Channels, Paths". On paths, it is saying "Shape 2 Shape Path" but I have already selected "Path" in toolbar. Should it say "Shape 2 Path"?

Comment: Yeah that means you converted it to a Shape at some point which is why its filled. Editing my answer for you

Comment: See edit for instructions on how to rectify it

Comment: Ryan: I deleted the shape path and restarted it and it seems to work now.

Comment: Yep that would work too lol